# Ошибка Runtime error 6 Overflow

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, overflow

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Все время возникает ошибка:

> Runtime error '6' Overflow в VBA.

Ошибка возникает в этой строке

```
"If WBook.Cells(q, 7) = ArrayPhoneAll(i) Then"
```

В столбце находятся телефонные номера или email, если поменять номер столбца, никакой ошибки не возникает.

```
Sub RegisterComplaintsPhone()

Dim n As Integer
Dim q As Long

n = 1


    
Set WBook = Workbooks("ДС_Реестр жалоб ГЛ и ЧАТ 09.07.2021222.xlsx").Worksheets("ДС_ГЛ, ЧАТ")

    
ReDim ArrayPhone(n) As Variant       
ReDim ArraySuccess(n) As Variant     
ReDim ArrayResult(n) As Variant      
ReDim ArrayPhone(n) As Variant       
ReDim ArrayFIO(n) As Variant         
ReDim ArrayDS(n) As Variant          
ReDim ArrayEmployee(n) As Variant    
ReDim ArrayEmployeeAll(n) As Variant 
ReDim ArrayDSAll(n) As Variant       
ReDim ArrayPhoneAll(n) As Variant    
ReDim ArrayResultAll(n) As Variant

 
n = 1
For w = 2 To 300
    If Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 2) <> "" Then
        ArrayPhoneAll(n) = Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 14).Value
        ArrayEmployeeAll(n) = Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 3).Value
        ArrayResultAll(n) = Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 2).Value
        Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 19) = ArrayPhoneAll(n)
        Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 20) = ArrayEmployeeAll(n)
        Worksheets("ДС").Cells(w, 21) = ArrayResultAll(n)
        n = n + 1
        'ReDim Preserve ArrayDSAll(n)
        ReDim Preserve ArrayPhoneAll(n)
        ReDim Preserve ArrayEmployeeAll(n)
        ReDim Preserve ArrayResultAll(n)
    End If
Next

n = 1 

MsgBox ArrayPhoneAll(1)
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayPhoneAll) - 1
    For q = 2 To 20000
        If WBook.Cells(q, 7) = ArrayPhoneAll(i) Then
            WBook.Cells(q, 31) = ArrayPhoneAll(i)
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Если я правильно прочитал код, то нужно для каждой непустой ячейки в диапазоне ДС!B2:B300 продублировать значения из колонок B, C и N в ту же строку в колонки T, U и S, а на листе "ДС_ГЛ, ЧАТ" для строк с найденными телефонными номерами в колонке G повторить этот же номер в колонке AT? Вообще-то это записывается немного проще

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. Основная суть в том чтобы создать массив с номерами телефонов в одном файле и проверить их совпадения в другом для дальнейшего заполнения совпадений. Но почему-то когда я проверяю другие столбцы, все в порядке, но именно при проверке совпадения телефонов (столбец G) возникает ошибка. Насчёт более простой записи, я понимаю, что мне ещё нужно много учиться)

Comment: Начните с просмотра, чему в момент возникновения ошибки равны переменные и значения соотв. ячеек.

Comment: Альтернативный способ (гораздо менее трудоёмкий): на вкладке Данные есть специальный инструмент для обработки таблиц. Просмотр трех-четырёх [**обучающих видео на ЮТубе**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+query+%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) займёт не более получаса, они все достаточно короткие (длинные лучше не смотреть, они скучные). Зато задача сопоставления данных из двух листов и манипуляции с ними сведутся к нескольким щелчкам мыши

Comment: С power query я знаком конечно, но то что вы видите лишь часть глобальной задачи, которую невозможно выполнить с помощью запросов)